# Shortest way to change multiple values of an array at once?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Perhaps too small question for it's own post...

So basically I'm looking for something like:

```
myarray[2, 3, 7] = 155, 34, true;
```

Is there some kind of line like this that works? Or what would be the shortest way to accomplish this, without changing all 3 manually?

Comment: Nothing built-in, you'd have to create your own function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for something like destructuring assignment, that's not coming until ECMAScript 6, and won't look quite like that.

To do what you seem to want, you'll just need to assign separately.

```
myarray[2] = 155;
myarray[3] = 34;
myarray[7] = true;
```

---

Or create a function that handles it for you.

```
function assign(obj, props, vals) {
    for (var i = 0; i < props.length; i++) {
        obj[props[i]] = vals[i];
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
assign(myarray, [2,3,7], [155,34,true]);
```

Comment: I wanted a single line thing because I need to do this for a large maze of arrays and can't be bothered to come up with some megacomplicated loop to do it all for me. That function seems to work perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could also opt to use the splice method like so:

```
    var myArray = [2, 3, 7];
    var otherArray = [155, 34, true];
      function arrayChanger(firstArray, secondArray){
        var orgLength = firstArray.length;
        for(i = 0; i < orgLength; i++){
        myArray.splice(i, 1, secondArray[i]);
     }
    return myArray;
    };
    arrayChanger(myArray, otherArray);
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cssimsek/fFte6/) that shows this solution in action.